# D3 does not support property gantt()

Tags: d3.js, gantt-chart

I'm trying to add a gantt chart to my application.  Started with the simple examples I've seen in the D3 site.  When I try something like this:

```
let gantt = d3.gantt().taskTypes(this.taskNames).taskStatus(this.taskStatus).tickFormat(format);
```

I get the error

> Property 'gantt' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'.

I am still no D3 version 3, and we haven't yet moved to Typescript 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality to create a gantt chart is not native to D3. You have to import it from [this code](https://github.com/dk8996/Gantt-Chart). [(CDN Version)](http://static.mentful.com/gantt-chart-d3v2.js)

Comment: Thanks Shea.  I probably should have realized that.  Looking at it now it seems pretty obvious.